# How to split and merge RxJS emitted array values?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, binary, observable

I have an RxJS Observable which emits binary data of type `Uint8Array` values. But not every emitted value contains exactly one complete data oject which can be processed on its own.

The data format of complete data objects consist of a start Byte (`0xAA`), some variable length data in between and an end byte (`0xFF`). The data in between is BCD encoded, this means principally it does not contain start or end bytes but only binary values from `0x00` to `0x99`.

Here is an example:

```js
// This is a mock of the source observable which emits values:
const source$ = from([
  // Case 1: One complete data object with start (0xAA) and end byte (0xFF)
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x01, 0x05, 0x95, 0x51, 0xFF,]),

  // Case 2: Two complete data objects in a single value emit
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x12, 0x76, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0x83, 0x43, 0xFF,]),

  // Case 3: Two uncomplete value emits which form a single data object
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x61, 0x85, 0x43, 0x67]),
  new Uint8Array([0x82, 0x73, 0x44, 0x28, 0x85, 0xFF]),

  // Case 4: A combination of Cases 2 and 3
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x61, 0x85, 0x43, 0x67]),
  new Uint8Array([0x55, 0x81, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0x73, 0x96]),
  new Uint8Array([0x72, 0x23, 0x11, 0x95, 0xFF]),
])

source$.subscribe((x) => {
  console.log('Emitted value as Hexdump:')
  console.log(hexdump(x.buffer))
})
```

[image: Hexdump logs]

**The goal is to receive only complete data objects. Maybe as a tranformed new observable?**

The example from above should be something like this:

```js
const transformedSource$ = from([
  // Case 1
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x01, 0x05, 0x95, 0x51, 0xFF,]),

  // Case 2
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x12, 0x76, 0xFF,]),
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x83, 0x43, 0xFF,]),

  // Case 3
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x61, 0x85, 0x43, 0x67, 0x82, 0x73, 0x44, 0x28, 0x85, 0xFF]),

  // Case 4
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x61, 0x85, 0x43, 0x67, 0x55, 0x81, 0xFF]),
  new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0x73, 0x96, 0x72, 0x23, 0x11, 0x95, 0xFF]),
])
```

1. Which RxJS methods or operators are suitable for this?
2. I thought about first to do splits at `0xFF` and then to do merges again. How to do this? Ideas from people with RxJS experience is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could try is splitting the chunks in order to process the bytes one by one, adding them to a buffer until the `0xff` byte appears in the stream and returning all buffered elements and reset the buffer for the next chunk:

```
let buffer = new Uint8Array();

transformedSource$.pipe(
        mergeAll(), // this splits your array and emits the single bytes into the stream
        mergeMap((next) => {
            buffer = new Uint8Array([...buffer, next]);
            if (next === 0xff) { (
                const result = buffer;
                buffer = new Uint8Array(); // resets the buffer
                return of(result); // will emit a completed chunk
            }
            return EMPTY; // won't emit anything 
        })
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

and in case you are not a fan of global variables or you want to reuse that code also for other streams, here an alternative solution with a custom operator:

```
const mergeChunks = () => {
    let buffer = new Uint8Array();

    return (source$) =>
        source$.pipe(
            mergeMap((next) => {
                buffer = new Uint8Array([...buffer, next]);
                if (next === 0xff) {
                    const result = buffer;
                    buffer = new Uint8Array();
                    return of(result);
                }
                return EMPTY;
            })
        );
} 

transformedSource$.pipe(
        mergeAll(),
        mergeChunks(),
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Here a [stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4iuua9?file=index.ts) to test it

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try and achieve the same using only built-in operators and not using outer the variable. This is more of an exercise and to answer the first part of the question:

> Which RxJS methods or operators are suitable for this

Going with variatons of the `buffer` operators would be the way to go. Answer from [@kruschid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66798067/4550158) was first, valid and probably something that I would go with myself if I had to choose.

```
source$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(t => t), // this transforms an array of bytes to single byte emissions
    multicast(
      () => new Subject<number>(),
      s =>
        s.pipe(
          bufferToggle(
            s.pipe(filter(v => v === 0xaa)),
            () => s.pipe(filter(v => v === 0xff))
          )
        )
    ),
    map(v => new Uint8Array(v))
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log(hexdump(x.buffer));
  });
```

Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7ie51w).